# Как записать весь полученный ответ в Json или в функцию Zip?

Tags: python, json, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

У меня есть некий ответ от сайта при парсинге . И я его хочу сделать более читабельным записать его в Json или Zip , если есть другие варианты с удовольствием   прочитаю)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
from pprint import pprint

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('table', {'style':'padding-top:10px;'})

    for rows in trs.find_all('tr'):
        pairs = rows.find_all('a')
        for pair in pairs:
            for elem in pair:
                print(elem)

def main():
    groups = {
        'T-691': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=26',
        'Т-717': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=62'
    }
    group = input()
    url = 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id={}'.format(groups[group])
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Я бы хотел чтоб информация выглядела так ('предмет':'ответ сайта','преподаватель':'ответ сайта') и тд .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в питоничий словарь ваши данные, если нужно будет сохранить в json, то передадите тот словарь. Приведите в вопросе что выводится при вызове get_data. И я так понимаю, что вы хотите, чтобы из get_data вернулись данные в человеко-читаемом виде?

Comment: я получаю расписание группы , но на сайте он имеет форму строчную , а у меня при выходе информации получается через столбец и он не читабелен ,  я пробовал делать сам , но у меня ничего не получалось. Да я хочу чтоб вернулся читаемый текст , а не просто набор)Буду очень признателен если поможете.

Comment: как мне это все записать правильно?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе тот ответ, что вы выводите в get_data (кнопка `править`) и дополнительно добавьте в вопрос ту таблицу с расписанием

Comment: Я изменил и добавил картинки , посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Информация о каждой паре находится в `<div class="pair">`. Можно найти все эти элементы и парсить каждый в ту структуру, которую хотите. Пример вывода каждой пары в словарь.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests


url = 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=26'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

# Ищем все пары
pairs_list = soup.select('div.pair')

# Получить пары только для первой недели
# pairs_list = soup.select_one('table').select('div.pair')    

def parse_pair(pair):
    """Функция для парсинга одной пары"""
    subject = pair.select_one('.subject').text
    teachers = [t.text.strip() for t in pair.select('.teacher') if t.text]
    group = pair.select_one('.group').text
    place = pair.select_one('.place').text

    return {
        'subject': subject,
        'teachers': teachers,
        'group': group,
        'place': place

    }


# Создам список из словарей. Каждый словарь - одна пара.
schedule_data = [parse_pair(pair) for pair in pairs_list]
```

---

```
[{'subject': 'ТестОтладкаПО',
  'teachers': ['Якимович К'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '408'},
 {'subject': 'МатемМоделир',
  'teachers': ['Клименко Д.Ф.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '429'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'ТестОтладкаПО',
  'teachers': ['Якимович К'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '408'},
 {'subject': 'ТРПО',
  'teachers': ['Шукалович С.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '408'},
 {'subject': 'БухУчет',
  'teachers': ['Яскевич И.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '504'},
 {'subject': 'БухУчет',
  'teachers': ['Яскевич И.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '504'},
 {'subject': 'ТРПО',
  'teachers': ['Шукалович С.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '403'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'ЗащитаКомпИнф',
  'teachers': ['Ванифатьев Е.А.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '403'},
 {'subject': 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'ФизКультура',
  'teachers': ['Шевченко О.Н.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': ' 25'},
 {'subject': 'ЗащитаКомпИнф',
  'teachers': ['Ванифатьев Е.А.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '414'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'БДиСистУпрБД',
  'teachers': ['Банцевич С.В.', 'Рагунович'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '410'},
 {'subject': 'ОснМенеджмента',
  'teachers': ['Тарайкович М.Г.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '519'},
 {'subject': 'ТРПО',
  'teachers': ['Шукалович С.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '410'},
 {'subject': 'ТестОтладкаПО',
  'teachers': ['Якимович К'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '408'},
 {'subject': 'МатемМоделир',
  'teachers': ['Клименко Д.Ф.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '429'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'ТестОтладкаПО',
  'teachers': ['Якимович К'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '408'},
 {'subject': 'ТРПО',
  'teachers': ['Шукалович С.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '408'},
 {'subject': 'БухУчет',
  'teachers': ['Яскевич И.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '504'},
 {'subject': 'БухУчет',
  'teachers': ['Яскевич И.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '504'},
 {'subject': 'БДиСистУпрБД',
  'teachers': ['Банцевич С.В.', 'Рагунович'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '410'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'ЗащитаКомпИнф',
  'teachers': ['Ванифатьев Е.А.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '403'},
 {'subject': 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'ФизКультура',
  'teachers': ['Шевченко О.Н.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': ' 25'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'},
 {'subject': 'БДиСистУпрБД',
  'teachers': ['Банцевич С.В.', 'Рагунович'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '410'},
 {'subject': 'ОснМенеджмента',
  'teachers': ['Тарайкович М.Г.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '519'},
 {'subject': 'ТРПО',
  'teachers': ['Шукалович С.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '410'},
 {'subject': 'ПрактРабПроф',
  'teachers': ['БагласоваЕ.В.'],
  'group': 'Т-691',
  'place': '416'}]
```

Этот результат вы можете преобразовать так, чтобы словари находились во вложенных списках. Каждый такой список будет представлять собой неделю из расписания. В результате может получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
schedule_data_grouped = [schedule_data[i: i+6] for i in range(0, len(schedule_data), 6)]

for week_schedule in schedule_data_grouped:
    print([pair['subject'] for pair in week_schedule])
```

---

```
['ТестОтладкаПО', 'МатемМоделир', 'ПрактРабПроф', 'ТестОтладкаПО', 'ТРПО', 'БухУчет']
['БухУчет', 'ТРПО', 'ПрактРабПроф', 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр', 'ЗащитаКомпИнф', 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр']
['ФизКультура', 'ЗащитаКомпИнф', 'ПрактРабПроф', 'БДиСистУпрБД', 'ОснМенеджмента', 'ТРПО']
['ТестОтладкаПО', 'МатемМоделир', 'ПрактРабПроф', 'ТестОтладкаПО', 'ТРПО', 'БухУчет']
['БухУчет', 'БДиСистУпрБД', 'ПрактРабПроф', 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр', 'ЗащитаКомпИнф', 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр']
['ФизКультура', 'ПрактРабПроф', 'БДиСистУпрБД', 'ОснМенеджмента', 'ТРПО', 'ПрактРабПроф']
```

Парсинг каждой строки таблицы:

```
# Берем первую таблицу и достаем отуда строки
table_rows = soup.select_one('table').select('tr') 

# Достаем из каждой строки все div.pair
pairs_list = [row.select('div.pair') for row in table_rows if row.select('div.pair')]

# Парсим всё в словари  
schedule_data = [[parse_pair(pair) for pair in week] for week in pairs_list]

for week in schedule_data:
    print([pair['subject'] for pair in week])
```

---

```
['ПрактРабПроф', 'ТРПО', 'ТестОтладкаПО', 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр', 'БДиСистУпрБД']
['ПрактРабПроф', 'МатемМоделир', 'ФизКультура', 'ТРПО', 'ОснМенеджмента', 'ТРПО']
['ПрактРабПроф', 'ТестОтладкаПО', 'ЗащитаКомпИнф', 'БухУчет', 'БухУчет', 'КонсПрогрИЯзПр']
['ПрактРабПроф']
```

Comment: А можно это сделать как-нибудь в табличной форме как на сайте?

Comment: @Илья, это https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dcc854881d24be835e3a9e81766ac33156ee0d9a/ascii_table__simple_pretty__rjust.py и еще вот (нужно будет установить tabulate): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dcc854881d24be835e3a9e81766ac33156ee0d9a/ascii_table__using_tabulate.py

Comment: @Илья полученный результат можно перегруппировать во вложенные списки, каждый будет содержать 6 элементов. Будет примерно повторять структуру таблицы на сайте. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Andrey Я столкнулся с такой проблемой , что он парсит и следующую неделю, потому что теги 'Pair' используется там же , я хотел узнать можно это как исправить?Написать регулярное выражение внутри pairs_list = soup.select('div.pair') ??

Comment: @Andrey или как-то можно в цикле исправить ?

Comment: @Илья там отдельная таблица для каждой недели. сделайте так: `pairs_list = soup.select_one('table').select('div.pair')` - выбираем первую попавшуюся таблицу и ищем в ней пары.

Comment: @Andrey , спасибо большое!

Comment: @Andrey есть такой еще вопрос , с чем может быть связанно , что расписание съезжает если взять другую группу , для парсинга , то расписание съезжает....

Comment: @Илья это потому, что мы просто достаем пары. Правильней будет парсить строки таблицы, для того, чтобы сохранялась структура. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Andrey и как это правильно написать ?

Comment: @Илья я ведь написал пример - последний кусок кода в ответе. С ним уже можете работать

Comment: @Andrey , понял спасибо !)